# Does BasicDataSource use connection pooling by default?

Tags: java, spring, apache-commons, spring-jdbc

I use the following to connect to DB (spring config)

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${oracleDriver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>
```

Does this internally use any connection pooling? If yes what is the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The BasicDataSource creates a pool internally. 
As in (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html), we can see that the default max number of active connections is 8 (maxTotal parameter).

If you do not want a connection pool, you should consider using an alternative such as:  `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SingleConnectionDataSource`